# Supabase - Upsert & multiple onConflict constraints

Tags: javascript, upsert, supabase

I cannot figure out how to proceed with an Upsert & "multiple" onConflict constraints. I want to push a data batch in a Supabase table.

My data array would be structured as follows:

```
items = [
    { date: "2023-01-26", url: "https://wwww.hello.com"}, 
    { date: "2023-01-26", url: "https://wwww.goodbye.com"}, 
    ...]
```

I would like to use the Upsert method to push this new batch in my Supabase table, unless if it already exists. To check if it already exists, I would like to use the date, and the url as onConflict criteria, if I understood well.

When I'm running this method

```
const { error } = await supabase
        .from('items')
        .upsert(items, { onConflict: ['date','url'] })
        .select();
```

I'm having the following error:

```
{
  code: '42P10',
  details: null,
  hint: null,
  message: 'there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification'
}
```

What am I missing? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass more than one column in the upsert into by adding a column in a string (instead of using an array):

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('items')
  .upsert(items, { onConflict: 'date, url'} )
```

Postgres performs unique index inference as mentioned in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

It is necessary to have unique or indexes for this to work, as you can read in the documentation above:

> `INSERT` into tables that lack unique indexes will not be blocked by
> concurrent activity. Tables with unique indexes might block if
> concurrent sessions perform actions that lock or modify rows matching
> the unique index values being inserted; the details are covered in
> Section 64.5. `ON CONFLICT` can be used to specify an alternative action
> to raising a unique constraint or exclusion constraint violation
> error.

Comment: ok, I still have the same error using that syntax... does the onConflict keys have to be unique?

Comment: Yes, that's also necessary as you can read in the docs linked in my answer. I'll update the answer to make this more explicit.

Comment: Any thoughts on handling a partial index? The CONFLICT condition would be something like `ON CONFLICT (col1, col2) WHERE col3=true` to have Postgres match the partial unique index on `col1,col2 WHERE col3=true`.